# How to code in R like do looping and find maximum from SAS

Tags: r, sas, max

Seems the same with my question before. But this one is to look for maximum from do looping.
I don't know how to do in R.
But the codes in SAS like:

```
data cek3;set cek;
do i = 1 to length(delq12);
X = substr(delq12,i,1);
if X in ('Z','B','1') then X = '0';
Y = put(X,2.);
MAX_DELQ = max(MAX_DELQ,Y);
end;
MAX_DELQ = max(MAX_DELQ-1,0);
run;
```

I Have data

```
delq12 <- c('ZZZZZZBZZZZZ','Z1ZZZZZZZZZZ','ZZ2ZZZZ22ZZZ','ZZZ3ZZ4ZZZZ0')
```

The answer I expected like this (this is answer from SAS):
[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: How about `sapply(stringr::str_split(delq12,""), function(x) max(as.numeric(x), na.rm=TRUE)-1)` giving `[1] -Inf    0    1    3`.  You can modify the function to avoid warning messages about `NA`s and no non-missing arguments to `max` and return `NA` or `0` in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the vector into a list of character vectors using `strsplit()`. Then use `sapply` to apply a function to get the max and return a vector of results.

In the function I use `x[grepl( '^\\d+$', x) ]` to remove non-numeric characters to avoid a warning before applying `as.numeric()`. Then using `c()` to concatenate with `0` avoids a warning about getting `max` of vector with only `NA`s (if there were no numbers in the original string).

So the code is:

```
max_delq <- delq12 |>
    strsplit('') |>
    sapply( \(x) { max( c( as.numeric( x[grepl( '^\\d+$', x) ] ) - 1, 0) ) } )
```